# Appending DataRow to DataTable filled from DataAdapter, clears all records

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataGridView` that has a `DataTable` bound to it, populated from `PostgreSQL` database with `Npgsql` .NET data provider library.

Populating records works, but when I want to append just a single records to already existing `DataTable`, previous records vanish:

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter npDataAdapterSingle = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from \"Weight\" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", this.npConnection);
DataTable tmpTable = new DataTable("tmpTable");
npDataAdapterSingle.Fill(tmpTable);

DSWeight.WeightRow row = this.dSWeight.Weight.NewWeightRow();
row.ItemArray = tmpTable.Rows[0].ItemArray;
this.dSWeight.Weight.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0); //Prepend, but i also tried this.dsWeight.Weight.Rows.Add(row);
```

If I select all records, without `LIMIT`'ing, then it works as expected. But I thought - why would i need to query the database all over again if I already have those records? That's why I want to `LIMIT`.

Maybe there is another solution, because I manually add new records to database and query them to add them to datatable, not the way it is supposed to be: add new records to datatable and them to database. I do it this way because I want the database to manage the id and timestamp fields and have datagridview to have these fields populated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about the data type of DSWeight.WeightRow and the scope of 'this' object since I get to see only a portion of the code and not the full method. This should probably work for you. please have a try.

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter npDataAdapterSingle = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from \"Weight\" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", this.npConnection);
DataTable tmpTable = new DataTable("tmpTable");
npDataAdapterSingle.Fill(tmpTable);

row =  tmpTable.NewRow();

foreach (DataColumn col in tmpTable.Columns)
   row[col.ColumnName] = tmpTable.Rows[0][col.ColumnName];

tmpTable.Rows.Add(row, 0);
```